# What would change in mathematics if we knew $\pi+e$ is rational?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

It is well known that there's no conclusion now whether $\pi+e$ is rational or not. What would happen if we knew that $\pi+e$ is rational?  Specifically, are there related open problems that would be settled?

Comment: Probably nothing; usually, its the techniques that lead to a new result that are the exciting part, rather than the result itself.

Comment: Human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together... mass hysteria!

Comment: @Mike: I like it! +1

Comment: Depends. If $\pi+e$ turned out to be rational, I would be inclined to believe that God is joking with us.

Comment: If $\pi + e$ turned out to be rational then there will be a much more simpler and natural relation between $e$ and $\pi $ than the traditional $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I'm not so sure. What if the denominator of $\pi+e$ has 2 million digits? Will $q\pi+qe=p$ be simpler than $e^{i\pi}+1=0$, if $q$ is that big?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I had in my mind that the relationship would be conceptually simple rather than visibly simple. In fact the existing Euler's relation between $e$ and $\pi$ seems to be the most impressive.

Comment: Restating the fact given by @ParamanandSingh, if $\pi + e$ was rational, or even algebraic, _Schanuel's hypothesis_ (currently an open problem in transcendence theory) would fall off, since $\pi + e = k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Q$ and $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$ are two different [expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression) in the exponential ring, and Schanuel's conjecture [essentially implies](http://www.fedoa.unina.it/2845/1/Terzo_Scienze_Matematiche.pdf) that _Euler's identity_ is the unique $\mathcal E$-algebraic relation between $e$, $\pi$ and $i$.

Comment: So I think it's not really true that _absolutely nothing_ would happen, considering the importance of Schanuel's conjecture in transcendental number theory.

Comment: Well, we'd know that $\pi e$ was irrational, so there's that.

Answer (score 8):

This is a comment that's too long for the usual format. If $\alpha=e+\pi$
can be written as a fraction of integers, both numerator and denominator
must be $\geq 2 \times 10^{32}$. To see this, let $A,B,C,D$ be
integers defined by

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
A &=& 3063742572717320569341511991159738 \\
B &=& 522834163445445988434458010516405 \\
C &=& 9765222175513935643148512770417523 \\
D &=& 1666455861030599542832067804101203 \\
\end{array}
$$

Then any good formal computing system will confirm to you that 
$\frac{A}{B} < \alpha < \frac{C}{D}$ and $BC-AD=1$. If $\alpha$
is rational, $\alpha=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q \in {\mathbb N}_{>0}$,
then $u=pB-qA$ and $v=qC-pD$ must be positive integers. But then
$p=Cu+Av\geq A+C \geq 2\times 10^{32}$ and similarly
$q=Du+Bv\geq B+D \geq 2\times 10^{32}$.

Answer (score 6):

It would imply in particular that $e$ is a [period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods), which it conjecturally isn't. There are deep reasons why $e$ is conjectured not to be a period, stemming (I believe) from Deligne's theory of motivic weights. I recommend taking a look at Kontsevitch and Zagier's fantastic article [*Periods*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kontzagi.pdf).

Comment: Interesting ref, thanks! +1

Comment: @Markus My pleasure!