# What are some of the implications of $\pi + e$ being rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, pi

Whether or not $\pi + e$ is rational is an open question. If it were rational, what would some of the implications be?

Comment: Interesting question.  I don't have much of a constructive observation to make, except that any of the consequences obviously cannot be things we know to be false, since that would decide the irrationality of $\pi+e$.

Comment: It would settle some open problems about the approximability of $\pi$ by rationals.

Comment: @BrianTung Well it *could*, it would just mean its not open anymore. Open problems have been solved on stack exchange before.

Comment: Someone asked before, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159350/why-is-it-hard-to-prove-whether-pie-is-an-irrational-number). You can see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel's_conjecture)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would change in mathematics if we knew $\pi+e$ is rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730117/what-would-change-in-mathematics-if-we-knew-pie-is-rational)

Answer (score 7):

One consequence would be that $e \pi$ is transcendental because, for any  $z$,  if $A=e+z$ and $B=ez$ are both algebraic then $e$ is a solution of $x^2-A x+B=0$, which makes $e$ algebraic. But it isn't.

Comment: If $e \pi$ is transcendental, what would the implications be for that?

Comment: @ John Carpenter . I dk  But  it might mean the discovery of a technique for answering Q's like it, or  perhaps the discovery  of  new class of numbers. One of David Hilbert's famous problem-set was the nature of $2^{\sqrt 2}$ and numbers like it, which led to the Gelfond Theorem....